# Plotting a line graph with python is giving invalid string error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a line graph using Python. My dataset contains strings for both the x- and y-axes. So, I inserted a new column "Sl No" as a numeric field to use as the y-axis.

Here is my code:

```py
# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Planned Path, Baseline Planned Path, Item Type)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = 1
dataset.insert(0, 'Sl No', range(start, start + dataset.shape[0]))

# Plot the line graph
plt.plot('Planned Path', 'Sl No')
plt.xlabel('<x_axis_label>')
plt.ylabel('<y_axis_label>')
plt.title('<graph_title>')
plt.grid(True)

# Show the graph
plt.show()
```

It's returning an error

```
'Sl No' not valid string (unrecognized character 'S')
```

I was expecting the code to plot a line graph.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to take the values from the dataset.

You just need to replace the line where the plotting function is called with `plt.plot(dataset['Planned Path'], dataset['Sl No'])`

Comment: thank you .... but i still see an error "Typeerror: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float value".... my data has only string fields